# Installed APK file is not appearing in home launcher

Tags: java, android

I have developed an application for Android box and installed that build on android 6,7,8,9 versions. App is getting opened in all versions. But in 6 and 7 versions the app is not visible on home launcher so, I opened the application through settings->apps.

Why the app is not coming on home launcher in 6 and 7 versions?

Comment: Post the AndroidManifest.xml of your app, especially the entry that contains your main activity data.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your personal help forum. Please remove the last sentence from your post. Also, if you want to get help, post your code and logs. Tell us what exactly isn't working.